# How do I run APK files in Eclipse emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I need some help on running APK files on emulator using Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Manually install your APK in your AVD:

Steps:

```
1) Paste your apk in your PLATEFORM-Tools in your Android SDK.
2) Now open your COMMAND-PROMPT.
3) make path till your adnroid sdk PLATEFORM TOOLS folder
4) now run command to find your emulator:

 adb devices
```

5) after this run this command to install the APK in your currently active emulator:

```
adb install abc.apk;
```

By this you can install your APK.

Answer (score 0):

That's not Eclipse emulator, it's Android Virtual Machine (AVD) and it's shipped with Android SDK. So you don't really need Eclipse. Just run the AVD from AVD Manager and wait for it to starts. After it starts it's like an android system, you can open browser download apk and install it. There are command you can send to AVD to install an APK as well. A good toll shipped with SDK is Monitor (DDMS on older version). You can explore many details of AVD there.